Fitting a planck curve on my spectrometer data
I collected data with a spectrometer and I am now trying to fit a Planck curve onto my data. For some reason I don't seem to get it to work. I think it has something to do with the scale of my intensity but I don't know how to fix that.
Here is my data: https://pastebin.com/xdLY6aLG. And this is the piece of code I tried to start with:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

h = 6.62607015e-34
c = 299792458
kb = 1.380649e-23

def planck_curve(wavelength, T):
    return (2 * h * c ** 2 / wavelength ** 5) * (1 / (np.exp(h * c / (wavelength * kb * T)) - 1))

data = pd.read_excel('6volt.xlsx')
wavelength = data['Wavelength'] / 1e9
intensity = data['Intensity']

popt, pcov = curve_fit(planck_curve, wavelength, intensity, p0=(3000,))

plt.plot(wavelength, intensity, label='Experimental Data')
plt.plot(wavelength, planck_curve(wavelength, *popt), label='Planck Curve Fit', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (m)')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Wavelength vs. Intensity with Planck Curve Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

T_fit = popt[0]
print("Geschätzte Temperatur (basierend auf dem Fit):", T_fit, "K")

I anyone has an idea on how I can get the planck curve onto my data I would be really thankful

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@flowist, what are you actually measuring as “intensity”, and what are its units? Also, confirm that your “wavelengths” are indeed wavelengths and the data is measured in nanometres.

If I use the wavelength at which the intensity is a peak (rather than fitting the whole curve) I get a temperature of about 4460 Kelvin. However, I would have to multiply the "intensity" by about 1e11 to get anywhere near a "fit", and, even then, the fit is very poor. Are you absolutely sure of your data (and what it represents)?

I suspect a mess between the definitions of the variables and symbols. First can you write down the equations in pure mathematical form instead of only in code.

The graphical representation of the data (intensity, wavelength) seems to have not the shape of a Planck curve.
